# React Cannot statically evaluate fs argument

Tags: reactjs, firebase-admin

I'm honestly not too sure what happened. I came back the next day and ran *npm run dev-client* (parcel client/src/index.html) and got the following log:

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234
‼  C:\Users\Tyler\Projects\React JS\project\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:205:77: Cannot statically evaluate fs argument
  203 |         }
  204 |         try {
> 205 |             var contents = config.startsWith('{') ? config : fs.readFileSync(config, 'utf8');
      |                                                                             ^
  206 |             return JSON.parse(contents);
  207 |         }
  208 |         catch (error) {
‼  Could not load existing sourcemap of "../../node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js".
‼  C:\Users\Tyler\Projects\React JS\project\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\credential.js:133:65: Cannot statically evaluate fs argument
  131 |     ServiceAccount.fromPath = function (filePath) {
  132 |         try {
> 133 |             return new ServiceAccount(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')));
      |                                                                 ^
  134 |         }
  135 |         catch (error) {
  136 |             // Throw a nicely formed error message if the file contents cannot be parsed
‼  C:\Users\Tyler\Projects\React JS\project\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\credential.js:244:63: Cannot statically evaluate fs argument
  242 |     RefreshToken.fromPath = function (filePath) {
  243 |         try {
> 244 |             return new RefreshToken(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')));
      |                                                               ^
  245 |         }
  246 |         catch (error) {
  247 |             // Throw a nicely formed error message if the file contents cannot be parsed
‼  C:\Users\Tyler\Projects\React JS\project\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\credential.js:337:35: Cannot statically evaluate fs argument
  335 |     var fileText;
  336 |     try {
> 337 |         fileText = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
      |                                   ^
  338 |     }
  339 |     catch (error) {
  340 |         if (ignoreMissing) {
```

And the execution immediately exits after throwing this error. I'm guessing it may have something to do with the config for firebase-admin that I provide, but I double-checked and this does not seem to be the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.